# insert into oracle table by script

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

please help me , i want to insert many data in excel file to oracle by using script,

for example this is my data

```
id    first_name   last_name   age
----   ----------  ---------  ------
1      jane         sana       23 
2      jame         bnn        34
3      sara         prencess   35
```

above are my data and i want to insert into my table by using script

Comment: Do  you know how to write SQL queries...

Comment: If you can save files as csv, look at using oracle external tables.

Comment: @Shiv yes i know, but i want to understand what is the script?

Comment: @enginnerava I have posted my answer..See whether this is helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query

```
-- Query to create table..
create table tablename(id int, first_name varchar(30), last_name varchar(30), age int);

-- Query to insert data..
insert into tablename values(1, 'jane', 'sana', 23);
```

Now run this insert command as many times as you want to insert the data into table `tablename`